# Regular expression for php address

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to work this out for ages. If someone could help would be great

```
  $address= str_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $address_line_1.' '.$address_line_2.', '.$town_village_city.', '.$state_province_county.', '.$postal_code.', '.$country);
    return str_replace('/,+/',', ',$address);
```

Want to format a address with single commars single space, any part of the address may be missing even the full address

dont want ,,,, to be return but simple no characters in this instance

Answer (score 1):

```
$address = implode(' ', array_filter(explode(' ',
   implode(', ', array_filter(explode(',', $address
))))));
```

This will work without regular expressions, but considering how much simple the regexen are, I'd stick with those.

Comment: this still brings back ,,,,  $address = $address_line_1.' '.$address_line_2.', '.$town_village_city.', '.$state_province_county.', '.$postal_code.', '.$country;
        return implode(' ', array_filter(explode(' ',
            implode(', ', array_filter(explode(',', $address
            ))))));

Comment: @MatthewChambers you need to put the entirety of the address into the very middle of all the function calls (i.e. where you have `address` now).  Use your head.

Comment: like so - 
        $address = $address_line_1.' '.$address_line_2.' '.$town_village_city.' '.$state_province_county.' '.$postal_code.' '.$country;
        return implode(' ', array_filter(explode(' ',implode(', ', array_filter(explode(',', $address))))));

Comment: still brings back - , , , , if address for each section is empty

Comment: @MatthewChambers without knowing the contents of those variables or the resulting `$address` string I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_replace()` instead of `str_replace()` if you want to work with regexps

Comment: thanks what about the regex though, though str replace was faster

Comment: @MatthewChambers not using regular expressions is faster.  That has nothing to do with functions.